# Where are my hats!

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I know the hats were a temporary thing but how will I ever know which hat i had, are they gone forever? will they even miss me?

In other words is there a way to view them after they are gone?

Thank you! (this is my first meta question! yay)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from the [Winterbash 2017 FAQ](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/faq)

> **What is going on? Why do I see hats?**
>
> From December 13th through January 2nd, you'll be able to earn hats all over the sites! Ask, answer, vote, edit, and chat, and you'll uncover hats hidden in all kinds of places.
>
> **What happens after January 2nd?**
>
> After January 2nd, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear. This is meant to be a fun end-of-year celebration, not a permanent addition to the site.

you can still see you hats for now on the `https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com` url but it'll eventually become like [`https://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com`](https://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com)

Comment: yes I knew that, thanks, but I'm asking is there any way to see them?

Comment: @RoshnaOmer edited. was actually just testing the 2016 and 2015 urls